# Overlay not hiding all underlying divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple `overlay`,

```
.overlay{
background-color:black;
opacity:0.5;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
}
```

over an already existing website. its working and covering the whole screen, but hiding only some of the divs, like its hiding the buttons, but not the search bar, or some tabs,

so actually few things are peeping through the overlay and and not getting behind it.I searched a lot for a solution but couldn't find one.

I tried to do `F12` and look at these peeping element's css but couldn't find anything that is worth bothering, no `position`, no `overflow`, that i could find.

Html code is a simple div tag with overlay as the class

Please help. Thanx!!

Comment: where are html code  ?

Comment: we could sure use some context :)

Comment: so try to give `height:100px; width:200px` and check how much area its covering

Comment: @Sumit patel HI Sumit,  html code is just a div with class .overlay

Comment: HI Aatif, its not about the area its covering... its on the complete screen... but some elements that just dont hide.. and are still showing through the overlay

Comment: see below example and any issue then comment me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, some elements are over your overlay.

i would suggest to try a higher z-index.

try:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolut;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Worked Fine . try this**

```css
.overlay{
background-color:black;
opacity:0.5;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
Overlay Div
  <div class="class-1">
  Test-1
  </div>
   <div class="class-2">
  Test-2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.trPic{ width:320px; height:240px; background: url(img/flower.png) no-repeat; border:5px solid #000000; } 
.trPic .redO{ position:relative; top:0px; width:320px; height:240px; background:#FF2400; opacity:0; }
.trPic:hover .redO { opacity:0.7; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html >
  <head>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class="trPic"> 
      <div class="redO"> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```